# What is the format of an odbc connectionstring to an oracle database using oracle wallet?

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

We want to connect to an Oracle 19c database on ssl connection using ODBC Linked service that uses Oracle wallet and we want to embed all the info in the connectionstring itself without needing any tns entries.

How can we construct this ODBC connectionstring ?

Comment: Have you tried these styles? https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-odbc-for-oracle/

Comment: Hi @pmdba - I did but was unable to find something related to oracle wallet configuration in this string..  can you please help

Comment: If it was going to work, you would need to craft the connection string with all of the appropriate TNS parameters (e.g. `PROTOCOL=TCPS`, etc.). You would still need the Oracle Client and a sqlnet.ora file to tell the client where the wallet was located. There's no way around that; those parameters can't be set in the connect string.